# DbfDataReader - file path exception

Tags: c#, path, filepath, datareader, dbf

I am using a nuget package `dbfDataReader` to read from a file and according from it's documentation here's how to implement it

```
var dbfPath = "path/file.dbf";
using (var dbfDataReader = new DbfDataReader(dbfPath, options))
{
    while (dbfDataReader.Read())
    {
        var valueCol1 = dbfDataReader.GetString(0);
    }
}
```

I have to pass the file path and I do it like this

```
 var dbfPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
```

and it throws and exception
[image]

but my variable is ok
[image]

In the nuget implementation they use **forward slash**  - `//` and `Path.GetFullPath` uses back slash - `\\`. Can I change the slashes?

Comment: The paths aren't the problem, there's probably a bug in the library.

Comment: This is not good news. It works if I set the `dbfPath` to an absolute path - @CodeCaster

Comment: Check filename. I think you have file.dbf at the end of the filename twice.